# No users or roles have SELECT permission on the SQL Server table but a user is able to select rows from it

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2017, sql-grant

I do not understand how the user, who is logged into SSMS with SQL Server authentication, is able to select rows from **MyTable**, when

MyTable
->  Properties
->Permissions

in SSMS is *blank*.  The user has had SELECT permission REVOKED.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the user us a member of a privileged server or database role. Check login and user role memberships.

Comment: Does a GRANT of SELECT on Table2, which has a foreign key relationship back to Table1, imply a GRANT of SELECT on Table1?

Comment: No, the grant does not imply select on the referenced table. I assume the problem SELECT by the user is done directly, not via a stored procedure or function (so that ownership chaining does not apply)?

Comment: You might also check for permissions granted at the database or schema level.

Comment: Correct, it is a select query issued in the editor window. I'm trying to get to a point where no one has any  SELECT permissions on the tables and I/O is exclusively through SPs on which a role has EXEC permissions.

Comment: I've also checked with TOAD in addition to SSMS.  When permissions are examined on a table,  TOAD shows GRANTS issued to roles as well. There are no GRANTS issued via roles on the table in question.

Comment: You need to tell us more about your setup, based on what you have described we can only guess.